# Distribute WPF app with WIX and .net Framework

Tags: wix

I need to distribute my WPF application. I am using WIX for building the Setup.exe.

But I also need to ensure that the .net framework 4.0 is first installed on the user's PC. I have downloaded dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe but how do I create a WIX installation that will contain MyApp.Msi and the .net framework redistribution file?

What I really want is to have just 1 Setup.exe that contains and runs both installs(my.msi and the .exe) in order.

Can this be done with WIX? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A setup bootstrapper is the file that could install the .NET framework. You can read about the WiX bootstrapper [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm). If you want the final output to be **one** .EXE file, you can pack the bootstrapper and the .MSI file into a new .EXE file using [IExpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress). IExpress is included in your Windows installation.

With WiX + IExpress you can create an installation package contained in **one** .EXE file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [WiX bootstrapper technology](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) (referred to as Burn) to create a single bootstrapper to install .NET and your .msi. Burn will enable you to embed the .NET redistributable and your .msi into a single setup.exe as well.